# Анимация по данным из CSV файла

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Всем привет! 
Ребята, помогите с проблемой. Есть CSV файл с полями: object_name,seconds,x_coordinate,y_coordinate. Необходимо сделать анимацию на svg/d3. Отображаются движения объектов (кружков) в зависимости от времени (seconds) и координат X,Y. В одно время на холсте могут находиться несколько объектов, либо пропадать и появляться новые (зависит от времени). Не нашел в интернете примеры циклов для d3 или svg. Буду рад любой помощи.

```
d3.csv("Animation.csv",type, function(error, data) {


var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("height", 200);



for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
 svg.selectAll("circle")   
.data(data)
.enter().append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.xcoord; })
.attr("cy", function(d) { return d.ycoord; }) 
.attr("r", 2.5);
    }



});

function type(d) {
   d.seconds = +d.seconds;
  d.xcoord = +d.xcoord;
  d.ycoord = +d.ycoord;
  return d;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]